# iOS 8: Admob banner ad implementation in "universal storyboard" (iPhone + iPhone 6 + iPad)

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, ios8, admob, xcode6

Apple introduced universal storyboard for developing one interface that works on all iPhone sizes and iPad sizes.

Can Admob banner ads support universal storyboard? iPhone 6 (plus)?

[Admob Banner ad size](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/banner#banner_size), which is not currently showing sizes for iPhone 6 (plus).

[Admob quick start guide](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/quick-start), which used a fixed 320*50 frame size. How can I add support for iPad and 4.7"/5.5" displays?

Here's the universal storyboard guide from [Raywenderlich], or [Apple]
->I can't post the links due to lack of reputations :(

Thanks!

Comment: same problem here..any solutions?

Comment: Any answer on this ??

Answer (score 8):

**There are two moments you should rely on:**

1. Its possible to use SmartBanners for every type of device (`kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait` or `kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape`). Banner with required size will be downloaded automatically (its a main pros of smart banners usage). As said in google docs:

> In portrait mode on phones, this will make the ad view either 320x50
>   or 360x50 in size, depending on whether the device is widescreen. In
>   landscape mode on phones, this will make the ad view anywhere from
>   480x32 to 682x32 depending on the height of the device.
>
> When an image ad won't take up the entire allotted space for the
>   banner, we'll center the image and use a hexagonal textile filler (see
>   image) to fill up the remaining space. Note that AdSense backfill ads
>   will be centered and have "transparent" filler.

so you shouldn't worry about that.

2. If you are using size classes (and autolayout consequently) you could setup separate height constraints for iPads and iPhones (90 and 50 px respectively) in storyboard (easier) or dynamically in code, using `bannerView.frame.size.height` value (better and flexible)

**To change a height value for a banner in Storyboard view you should:**

1. Add a `90 px` height constraint for `w:Any h:Any`
2. Switch to `w:Compact h:Regular` (to select all iPhones)
3. Find a constraint, select it and press `Cmd+Delete`. That will disable constraint for current size class
4. Add new `50 px` constraint

Comment: Does this really work? Do YOU get full width banners for any device width? I cannot for the life of me get anything but the "320x50 test banner" even for iPhone 6 Plus, even using kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait.

Answer (score 1):

At this point in time, I don't think there's really a decent solution here. It's speculation on my part, but I think the real issue is that Google just doesn't yet have the correctly-sized creatives to serve up 6 and 6Plus ads.

That said, I'm using the following code, in the hopes that, in the future, the "kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait" size will cause adMob to serve up content that's sized properly for the 6 and 6Plus. This code currently results in a 320x50 banner being served to my apps when running on the 6 and 6Plus. (Note also that my app is portrait-only, but it wouldn't be too much trouble to add landscape support to this.)

```
// Create adMob ad View (note the use of various macros to detect device)
if (isiPad) {
    _adMobView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeFullBanner];
}
else if (isiPhone6) {
    _adMobView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
}
else if (isiPhone6Plus) {
    _adMobView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
}
else {
    // boring old iPhones and iPod touches
    _adMobView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
}
```

Comment: Were you able to get kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait working so far?